# I get weird quilts when I try to load text from a text file?

Tags: c

The purpose of the function is that it should be able to read text from a text file and later save it to an array list. The program somehow manages to load strange characters. In the text file are the following products.

Apple 2.00 kg

Bannan 3.00 kg

Milk 2.00 l

The output is about that way

1. ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════²Ò©Ô# -431602080.00 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════²Ò©Ô #
2. ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════²Ò©Ô# -431602080.00 ════════════════════════════════════════════════²Ò©Ô #
3. ════════════════════════════════════²Ò©Ô# -431602080.00 ════════════²Ò©Ô #

   ```
   void loadList(struct ShoppingList* list){

     char fileName[20];
     printf("Enter file name: ");
     while (getchar() != '\n');
     gets(fileName);

     FILE* file;

     if ((file = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL) {
         free(list->itemList);
         list->itemList = NULL;
         list->length = 0;

         if ((list->itemList = (struct GrocaryItem*)malloc(sizeof(struct GrocaryItem) * (list->length + 1))) != NULL) {
              for (int x = 0; (fscanf(file, "%s \t %f \t %s \n", list->itemList[x].productName, &list->itemList[x].amount, list->itemList[x].unit)) > 0; x++) {

                  if ((list->itemList = (struct GrocaryItem*)malloc(sizeof(struct GrocaryItem) * (list->length + 1))) != NULL) {
                       list->length = x + 1;
                  }
                  else {
                      printf("Error");
                  }
              }
          }
          else {
              printf("Error");
          }

     }
     else {
         printf("Error");
     }
    }
   ```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I suggest changing `fscanf(file, "%s \t %f \t %s \n", ...) > 0` to `fscanf(file, "%s%f%s", ...) == 3`. That is, remove all the noise from the format string, and check the exact number of conversions.

Comment: The `malloc` after `fscanf` throws away all data that was just read. Try `realloc` instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane Still not working

Comment: @dxiv I tried to use realloc but I got an error message saying "Exception thrown at 0x7792EC7A (ntdll.dll) in Lab 6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x42340000."

Comment: @LeoParden Then you used it wrong, and you should post *that* code with the description of the problem. But the way it is now can not possibly work, because you read data into a buffer, then immediately change the pointer to another freshly malloc'd buffer. This loses the previously read data, and also leaks the previously allocated memory because there is no saved pointer to it to free at the end.

Comment: @dxiv I get the same error message when I only use realloc. I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: @LeoParden No one can guess what's not working in code that you do not show.

Comment: _"weird quilts"_?

Comment: Note: `GrocaryItem` should probably be `GroceryItem`.